# CI_Loader eror when upload in Hosting

Tags: php, codeigniter

I use Codeigniter 2.20, I mean I will use template for header and footer and I put in

```
application/core/MY_Loader.php
```

when I run in local , it's work. But when I upload in hosting, something bad was happen like

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_Loader::templateklien() in /home/u798792514/public_html/application/controllers/client.php on line 44
```

Refers to this....

```
public function templateklien($template_name, $vars = array(), $return = FALSE) {
    $content = $this->view('template/client/header', $vars, $return);
    $content .= $this->view($template_name, $vars, $return);
    $content .= $this->view('template/client/footer', $vars, $return);

    if ($return) {
        return $content;
    }
}
```

Whats wrong with this?